# Same Matplotlib code produces different images on different machines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Matplotlib function to create a confusion matrix and save it to a file:

```py
def pretty_print_conf_matrix(y_true, y_pred,
                             classes,
                             normalize=False,
                             title='{} Confusion matrix'.format(describe_test_setup()),
                             cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                             out_dir=None):
    """
    Code adapted from: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py
    """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=classes)

    # Configure Confusion Matrix Plot Aesthetics (no text yet)
    cax = ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=16)
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(classes)))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(classes)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(classes)
    ax.set_yticklabels(classes)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=14)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=14)
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right', rotation_mode='anchor')
    plt.colorbar(cax)

    ax.set_ylabel('True label', fontsize=16)
    ax.set_xlabel('Predicted label', fontsize=16, rotation='horizontal')

    # Calculate normalized values (so all cells sum to 1) if desired
    if normalize:
        cm = np.round(cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(), 2)  # (axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]

    thresh = cm.max() / 1.5 if normalize else cm.max() / 2

    # Place Numbers as Text on Confusion Matrix Plot
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        ax.text(j, i, cm[i, j],
                 ha="center",
                 va="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black",
                 fontsize=12)

    #fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show(block=False)

    if out_dir is not None:
        out_file = os.path.join(out_dir, 'Confusion Matrix{}.png'.format(describe_test_setup()))
        fig.savefig(out_file, dpi=300)
```

This works well on two of my machines, but on the third it produces ugly squashed images. They are all running the same source code.

Example of it working properly (resolution 4500x4500):

[image]

Example of it working poorly (resolution 1028x715):

[image]

I thought this could be caused by me running different matplotlib versions, but using `pip freeze` I can see `matplotlib==3.1.2` on both machines.

Any ideas what the cause might be?

Comment: The [matplotlib rc file](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files) sets many default parameters for matplotlib. It's a good place to start looking.

Comment: probably the backend is different. Do matplotlib.get_backend() on each machine.