# How to identify cause of Matplotlib producing different outputs depending on running machine?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run a matplotlib script locally, the output is great:

[image]

But when I run the same matplotlib script on a remote machine, the output removes the colorbar tick labels and squashes the colorbar label:

[image]

The python versions and matplotlib versions are identical, but the operating systems are different. How do I identify the cause of this discrepancy?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470196/same-matplotlib-code-produces-different-images-on-different-machines) suggested running `matplotlib.get_backend()` to check whether the backends are the same. The first image's backend is `'module://backend_interagg'` and the second image's backend is `agg`. What does this mean? Could this be the source of the discrepancy? If so, how do I change the backend?

Comment: use [`use`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.use) to set the backend

Comment: Setting the backend might be the solution, but can you provide more information? How do I identify which backend is problematic and which isn't?

Comment: `module://backend_interagg` is PyCharm's backend to show the plots in the toolwindow, so I'd start using a non-interactive backend locally (by disabling the toolwindow, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49070994/3944322)) and see if it looks differently

Comment: Is there a way to use PyCharm's backend on a remote machine?

Comment: I think it only works from within PyCharm (and is interactive, so I guess it's not what you want).

Comment: It also looks like you have pretty different versions of Matplotlib running.  You should also be careful about any manual fiddling you had to do to get the first plot the way you wanted it.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I haven't done any fiddling locally. It's just plotting three heatmaps with seaborn and then `plt.show()`.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am plotting locally through my IDE PyCharm, which Stef has pointed out uses a different backend.

Comment: sure, but the size of the images should be the same, and the colorbars should be labelled the same etc.  So you are likely using different versions of Matplotlib.